# In PHP how do i use a function where one of the parameters is a class:

Tags: php, magento

In magento 2.2.1 there is a function that i am trying to use that has a class as a parameter:

```
public function add($sku, \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterface $tierPrice);
```

This used to just have 4 parameters that were passed to it and was used like below:

```
$this->tierInterface->add($sku,$groupId,$price, '1');
```

Now however the second parameter needs to be used in place of these old parameters where `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterface $tierPrice` has within the below methods that i need to use instead:

- `public function setQty($qty);`
- `public function setValue($value);`
- `public function setCustomerGroupId($customerGroupId);`

How can i use these new methods to correctly pass the values to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 2 there is a [concrete implementation](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/TierPrice.php) of `ProductTierPriceInterface` that you should use which is named `TierPrice`.

Your new code would look like this :

```
# Pretty sure dependency injection should be needed there.
$tierPrice = new TierPrice();
$tierPrice->setQty(1);
$tierPrice->setValue($price);
$tierPrice->setCustomerGroupId($groupId);

$this->tierInterface->add($sku, $tierPrice);
```

Comment: So add the class to my construct : \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterface $tierPrice then i can use like $tierPrice = $this->$tierPrice or new $this->tierPrice and then set like you have suggested?

Comment: Ok dont worry think i have it. Still having issues with one product not working but thanks.